# Entity Framework Nested Entities Add or Update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables. Client and Conversations. In the view for creating/editing clients, there is also an option for adding Conversations associated to the client (using BeginCollectionItem). When I try to update (in the edit view) using the following code:

```
db.Clients.Attach(client);
db.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified; //Conversations not added
```

The fields in the Client table are updated but the conversations are not added. I do not face this issue while creating a client.

```
db.Clients.Add(client); //Conversations are added
```

Is it possible to accomplish this without having to add the conversations explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First attach the client, then add the conversation to it:

```
var client = db.Clients.Attach(new Client());
client.Conversations.Add(conversation);

db.SaveChanges();
```

No need to change the client's state programatically.. if you attach the client to the context first, entity framework will track the changes.

Edit:

Since the object is already constructed when you attach it to the context, you need to tell EF that the conversation children have either been Added or Modified

```
foreach (var conversation in client.Conversations)
{
    if (conversation.Id == default(int))        
        context.Entry(conversation).State = EntityState.Added;
    else
        context.Entry(conversation).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry if my point wasn't clear, I am not adding the conversations manually in code. They are bound in the model that is posted back. Conversations are already associated with the client. Now if I were to adopt your code, I did again need to explicitly link conversations to the client.

Comment: Well Martin, it worked but I still feel its more explicit. I would have thought these kind of task being performed in the background. Works for now! Thanks